# Connect Google sheets to azure Sql Database

Tags: azure

HI i would like to connect my google sheets to azure and update my table automatically as any changes done in google sheets

i have try using Microsoft flow but doesn't work

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?If so,you could mark it for answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below three microsoft services to collaborate with Google sheets.

- Logic Apps   All Logic Apps regions except the following: -   Azure
  China regions
- Flow All Flow regions PowerApps
- All PowerApps regions

Mentioned in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/googlesheet/).

Also,you could vote up and push this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/35102110-google-sheets-connector) to add Google sheet connector in ADF.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SeekWell](https://seekwell.io), you can schedule refreshes from Sheets to your database up to every 5 minutes.

Disclaimer - I'm a cofounder at SeekWell.

Answer (score 0):

It's late but I think it can be helpful for someone.

I like to use Skyvia for connecting Google Sheets and SQL Azure without coding:

https://skyvia.com/data-integration/integrate-google-sheets-sql-azure
All I need is to specify the connections to Google Sheets and SQL Azure and select data to replicate. Skyvia will copy the specified Google Sheets data to SQL Azure and maintain this copy up-to-date automatically with incremental updates.